# Костюмные попапы и маркеры на google maps js api

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать подобные маркеры с всплывающими окошками при наведении на них?

[image: Пример гугл карты с кастовыми маркерами]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать попап на маркер при помощи [Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows), а уж верстку внутри него можете создать совершенно любую:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info Windows</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
      // When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
            '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
            'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Пример](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)